# Replace item in list upon negative index as input

Tags: python

Currently, I have a list as such:

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and what I'm trying to do is to emulate 'aList[index] = item' function in python. the program prompts the user for input of negative index and the item to replace.

```
enter negative index: -2
enter item to replace: 7
```

this would give me:

```
[1,2,3,7,5]
```

since, when the index is negative, python starts counting from the back of the list. Here's my code:

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5]

index = int(input("Enter index:"))
item = int(input("Enter item:"))

j = -1                            #-1 means the counter should begin with -1 not 0
start = len(aList)-1             #i want python to start from the back of the list


while j<start:
    if j == index:
        aList[j] = item
    j-=1                      
print(lst)
```

I'm getting an infinite loop because of the j-=1 and I'm wondering if I'm emulating it correctly?

Comment: I don't get it: `j>start` is always false. You don't even enter the loop..

Answer (score 1):

I think first you need to clear you concept about array.

---

### What is Array.?

Arrays a kind of data structure that can store a fixed-size sequential collection of elements of the same type. An array is used to store a collection of data, but it is often more useful to think of an array as a collection of variables of the same type.

Instead of declaring individual variables, such as number0, number1, ..., and number99, you declare one array variable such as numbers and use numbers[0], numbers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKnCs.jpg), and ..., numbers[99] to represent individual variables. A specific element in an array is accessed by an index.

All arrays consist of contiguous memory locations. The lowest address corresponds to the first element and the highest address to the last element.

[image: Graphical Representation of Array]

---

### Array In Python

---

To define a list you simply write a comma separated list of items in square brackets:

```
myList=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This looks like an array because you can use "slicing" notation to pick out an individual element - indexes start from 0. For example

```
print myList[2]
```

will display the third element, i.e. the value 3 in this case. Similarly to change the third element you can assign directly to it:

```
myList[2]=100
```

The slicing notation looks like array indexing but it is a lot more flexible. For example

```
myList[2:5]
```

is a sublist from the third element to the fifth i.e. from myList[2] to myList[4]. notice that the final element specified i.e. [5] is not included in the slice.
Also notice that you can leave out either of the start and end indexes and they will be assumed to have their maximum possible value. For example

```
myList[5:]
```

is the list from List[5] to the end of the list and

```
myList[:5]
```

is the list up to and not including myList[5] and

```
myList[:]
```

is the entire list.
List slicing is more or less the same as string slicing except that you can modify a slice. For example:

```
myList[0:2]=[0,1]
```

has the same effect as

```
myList[0]=0
myList[1]=1
```

Finally is it worth knowing that the list you assign to a slice doesn't have to be the same size as the slice - it simply replaces it even if it is a different size.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need a loop, when you can just access the elements by index:

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5]
index = int(input("Enter index:"))
item = int(input("Enter item:"))
aList[index] = item
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your loop is infinite...the variable 'j' keeps getting more negative and you're comparing it so 'start', which is the length of the list minus one.